# How to reset interval of set interval function

Tags: javascript, web, backend

I'm wondering how to stop this function when `next` is not equal to `targetVar` and here's my code :

```
function detectChange(next,targetVar){
    if (next==targetVar){
        waktuSholat();
        console.log("Waktu Sholat Berhasil Di Perbarui");
    } else if (next!=targetVar){
        speakIt();
    }
}
setInterval(detectChange, 2000);
```

I don't know how to stop this interval. I really appreciate your help and your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Store the id returned by `setInterval` and call `clearInterval` to stop it. Note that `detectChange` is called each time without any arguments, so both `next` and `targetVar` are always `undefined`; perhaps you meant to check global variables instead.

```
function detectChange(next,targetVar){
    if (next==targetVar){
        waktuSholat();
        console.log("Waktu Sholat Berhasil Di Perbarui");
    } else {
        speakIt();
        clearInterval(id);
    }
}
let id = setInterval(detectChange, 2000);
```

Comment: Question should be marked as dupe

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Alright, i just realized. Thank You